# Static meniscus - analytical solution

Tags: calculus, fluid-dynamics, nonlinear-analysis

I have been trying to understand how to find the solution to the following ODE

$$\frac{d}{dx} \frac{1}{[1+(dh/dx)^2 ]^{1/2} }=h$$ where $h=f(x)$.

It would be great if someone could help me understand the problem.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonomous_system_(mathematics)#Second_order